# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: asp.net

when i upload my application in online and  type the url and i am getting this error please help me this is error

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Source Error
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: set the enabled attribute on your customerrors tag in web.config to false. This way you will be able to see the detailed asp.net error. Then post it here if you canno diagnose it

Comment: ya i did it but no use it is showing the same error

Comment: can u check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 i might helpful.